# C++ advantages in working with videodata and videodevices

Tags: c++, detection, face-detection

What are the advantages of C++ over the others languages in working with videodata and videodevices (developing object detection program). Thank you.

Comment: Wrong place to ask such a question. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place. But with care and pain you can get efficient binary executables with C and C++; consider also other languages (OpenCL to run on the GPU, perhaps Ocaml ... Common Lisp... which have good compilers)

Comment: Thank you. Going to programmers right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for object detection, you could use python, matlab, java and c++. You have to use c++ if you need substantially speed improvement (C++ is the fastest in most of the cases). You could also use OpenCv easily with c++ for face and object detection.